# I want to Return a Header,Body,Trailer from the SQL

Tags: sql

Issue is When There is any Column of the Database Field is Null we've to Replace with the Column Length.
For example I've 3 columns Name NVARCHAR(2), DOB NVARCHAR(8),Address NVARCHAR(10)

| Name | DOB | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 05-01-1995 | MJRSquare |
| a2 | 26-04-1999 |  |
| a1 |  | PLR1 |

and The O/P I need is :

`a105011995MJRSquare` --> All Columns have Data Then it has to display like this
`a226041999`          --> There is No address then add Length Of the Column i.e., 10
`a3        PLR1`      --> There is No DOB then add Length Of the Column i.e., 8

Name - 1 to 2
DOB - 3 to 10
Address - 11 to 20

The line from the above O/P it is Fixed Length Columns.

Tried to Create a Function with Padding But it is not replacing the Null values.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using (And "SSMS" is not a "database" at all)

Comment: What's the actual datatype of the DOB column? While you've said it has a length of 8 your data has 10 chars. Please also update your question with the SQL you've managed to write on your own

Comment: @NickW added Datatype

Comment: Again, it can't be 8 chars because your sample data has 10 chars ("05-01-1995" is 10 chars long) - or your sample data is incorrect. Please fix one or the other so the information you provide is consistent

Answer (score 0):

Judging by datatype, I would assume this is Microsoft SQL Server.
There are handy functions for this situation: `COL_LENGTH` and `REPLICATE`.
But I think it would be easier to change spaces to i.e dots, since nvarchar datatype doesn't preserve trailing spaces.

```
create table t(id int, b nvarchar(32), c nvarchar(12));

insert into t values
  (1, 'asd', 'dsa'),
  (2, NULL, 'qwe'),
  (3, 'fff', NULL),
  (NULL, 'gggg', '4141');

select
  ISNULL(
    cast(id as nvarchar(256)),
    REPLICATE('.', COL_LENGTH('t', 'id'))
  ) + ISNULL(b, REPLICATE('.', COL_LENGTH('t', 'b')))
    + ISNULL(c, REPLICATE('.', COL_LENGTH('t', 'c')))
from
  t;
```

you get

```
1asddsa
2................................qwe
3fff............
....gggg4141
```